# KeySpec throws "Salt not found" - Salt isn't a requirement

Tags: java, exception, encryption, passwords

I am currently working on a small bit of code, which is supposed to encrypt a byte[] before it gets stored inside a file. In the following snippet, I am trying to generate a SecretKey from a Password using PBKDF2.

```
public SecretKey deriveKey(String password)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    SecretKeyFactory kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec specs = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
    SecretKey key = kf.generateSecret(specs);
    return key;
}
```

This throws an exception

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Salt not found

at the last line before the return statement. This seems quite confusing to me as the PBEKeySpec does explicitly not require any more parameters as seen [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/PBEKeySpec.html#constructor_detail).

This is not a tragedy, I was to add salt later anyway and it's even already defined further above but I was curious whether anybody knows why this happens. I might be doing something terribly wrong and just didn't notice.

Answer (score 3):

It is not about whether PBEKeySpec class needs a salt or not. The algorithm [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
needs a salt. The API is a generic api which should cater to multiple algorithms, some of which might be defined in future.